# jQuery bassistance validate, how to prevent printing to console.log

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

When running the validation plugin, I can see that it prints to the console in Firebug (even if I have `debug: false`).

When running the application in IE9/IE8 it fails, unless in debug mode, i.e. shift+F12. When in debug mode I can see that it prints to the IE console and the application actually works.

How do I configure the plugin in order to stop the printing to console ( I assume IE cannot handle this when not in debug mode)? Or is this a bug in the validation plugin so I have to remove those lines myself?

The plugin is printing from defaultShowErrors inte the plugin.

Here is on example of my validation codes:

```
function registerAccountValidation(){
    $("#registerform").validate({ 
        errorContainer: "#messageBox1",
        errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox1 ul",
        wrapper: "li", 
        debug:false,
        rules: {     
            owner_first_name: "required",
            owner_surname: "required",
            owner_email: { // compound rule 
                email: true,
                required: true,
                remote: "http://" + hostname +  "/modules/core/account/is_available.php"
            }, 
            email2: { 
                equalTo: "#email"
            },
            username: {
                required: true,
                remote: "http://" + hostname +  "/modules/core/account/is_available.php"
            },
            password: {
                required: true
            },
            password2: {
                equalTo: "#password"
            },                                
            owner_phone_number: "required",
            company_address: "required",
            zipcode: "required",
            city: "required",
            country: {
                required: true
            },
            company_name:{
                required: true,
                remote: "http://" + hostname +  "/modules/core/account/is_available.php"
            },
            company_link: {
                required: true,
                remote: "http://" + hostname +  "/modules/core/account/is_available.php",
                alpha: true
            }
        }, 
        messages: { 
            owner_first_name: {
                required: "First name is missing"
            },
            owner_surname: "Surname is missing",
            owner_email: { // compound rule 
                email: "Please specify a correct e-mail address" ,
                required: "E-mail is missing",
                remote: "E-mail address already registered"
            }, 
            email2: { 
                equalTo: "E-mail addresses must be equal"
            },
            username: {
                required: "Username is missing",
                remote: "Username is already registered"
            },
            password: {
                required: "Password is missing"
            },
            password2: {
                equalTo: "Passwords must be equal"
            },
            owner_phone_number: "Phone number is missing",
            company_address: "Address is missing",
            zipcode: "Zip code is missing",
            city: "City is missing",
            country: {
                required: "Country is missing"
            },
            company_name: {
                required: "Company name is missing",
                remote: "Company name already registered"
            },
            company_link: {
                required: "Link is missing",
                remote: "Link is already registered",
                alpha: "Must only contain a-z and A-Z and no blank space"
            }
        }
    }); 
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Removing the printing to console in the plugin actually solves the problem. But I prefer doing it in a formal way, if there is any. Don't want to run into issues while updating the plugin in the future.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan, why did you remove the information about from what function in the plugin the printing to console is done?

Comment: You added that in while I was editing your code jumble, I didn't remove it intentionally.

Answer (score 0):

In case a quick and dirty solution is enough, you could define a dummy console.log for the browsers not having a real one:

```
if(!(window.console && window.console.log)){
    window.console = {
        log: function(){}
    };
}
```

This would at least make the errors go away if finding the actual issue proves hard.

Comment: Thanks. I think I stick with editing the plugin if there isn't any formal way of doing it right now. Check my update.